# Spring Data - Build where clause at runtime

Tags: spring, jpa, where-clause

In Spring Data, how can I append more conditions to an existing query?

For example, I have the CrudRepository below:

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface MyRep extends CrudRepository<MyObject, Long> {
  @Query("from MyObject mo where mo.attrib1 = :attrib1")
   List<MyObj> findMyObjects(String attrib1, String conditions);
}
```

At runtime, I will need to call "findMyObjects" with two params. The first param is obviously the value of attrib1. the second param will be a where clause that would be determined at runtime, for example **"attrib2 like '%xx%' and attrib3 between 'that' and 'this' and ..."**. I know this extra where condition will be valid, but I don't know what attributes and conditions will be in it. Is there anyway to append this where clause to the query defined in the @Query annotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. There is no straightforward way to achieve that.

You'll want to use [custom reporistory methods](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behavior) where you'll be able to inject an `EntityManager` and interact with `EntityManager.createQuery(...)` directly.

Alternatively, you can build dynamic queries using [Specifications or QueryDsl](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/).

Comment: Thanks crizzis. I ended up injecting an EntityManager as you suggested. I get the EntityManager by autowiring in the rest controller.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up injecting an EntityManager that I obtained in the rest controller. Posting what I did here for criticism:

The repository code:

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface MyRepo extends CrudRepository<MyObject, Long> {

   default List<MyObject> findByRuntimeConditions(EntityManager em, String runtimeConditions) {
      String mySql = "<built my sql here. Watch for sql injection.>";
      List<MyObject> list = em.createQuery(mySql).getResultList();
      return list
   }
}
```

The Rest controller code:

```
@RestController
public class DataController {

    @Autowired
    EntityManager em;

    // of course watch for sql injection    
    @RequestMapping("myobjects/{runtimeConditions}")
    public List<MyObject> getMyObjects(@PathVariable String runtimeConditions) {
      List<MyObject> list = MyRepo.findByRuntimeConditions(em, runtimeConditions);
      return list;  
    }
}
```